# css - position full width block behind centered page

Tags: css

[example](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ccwlqnaa)

I know this will be really simple but I'm stuck sorry.

I have a centered page with a width (the grey area in my example) and I want to have block behind it that is full width (the red area in my example).

The page needs to have a slight margin at the top to show the block behind it.

How can I have a full with block and have a page positioned on top.

I have it looking something like I want but thats with negative margin on the page area

Answer (score 2):

You can use position absolute. But dont work with pixels. It is bad idea for mobile devices.

These code aligns div to center.

left:50%;

transform:translate(-50%,0);

```css
.top{
width:100%;
height:100px;
background:red;
}
.inline-class{
height:200px;
width:90%;
background:grey;
position:absolute; 
top:50px;
left:50%;
transform:translate(-50%,0); 
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
</div>
<div class="inline-class">İnline Class</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `position: absolute` to position one element over another.

```
.page {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 50px;
}
```

`position: absolute` positions your element relative to it's first ancestor, so it basically ignores the position of it's siblings.